# how can I place show the circle div on top slider div?

Tags: html, css

The problem is the circle div is not appearing. I need to show the circle div on top of everything but I can't. How can I show the circle div?

```css
.home {
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.home .slide {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  z-index: 1;
  display: none;
  padding: 0 15px;
  animation: slide 2s ease;
}

.home .slide.active {
  display: flex;
}

@keyframes slide {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1);
    /*1.1*/
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}

.containers {
  max-width: 1170px;
  margin: auto;
}

.home .containers {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.home .caption {
  width: 50%;
}

.home .caption h1 {
  font-size: 42px;
  color: #000000;
  margin: 0;
}

.home .slide.active .caption h1 {
  opacity: 0;
  animation: captionText .5s ease forwards;
  animation-delay: 1s;
}

.home .caption p {
  font-size: 18px;
  margin: 15px 0 30px;
  color: #222222;
}

.home .slide.active .caption p {
  opacity: 0;
  animation: captionText .5s ease forwards;
  animation-delay: 1.2s;
}

.home .caption a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 30px;
  background-color: #000000;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.home .slide.active .caption a {
  opacity: 0;
  animation: captionText .5s ease forwards;
  animation-delay: 1.4s;
}

@keyframes captionText {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateX(-100px);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateX(0px);
  }
}

.home .controls .prev,
.home .controls .next {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  top: 50%;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  margin-top: -20px;
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #FF5722;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 40px;
  font-size: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all .5s ease;
}

.home .controls .prev:hover,
.home .controls .next:hover {
  background-color: #000000;
}

.home .controls .prev {
  left: 0;
}

.home .controls .next {
  right: 0;
}

.home .indicator {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: 30px;
  z-index: 2;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.home .indicator div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #FF5722;
  border-radius: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 25px;
  margin: 0 3px;
}

.home .indicator div.active {
  background-color: #000;
}
```

```html
<section class="home">
  <div class="circle" style="height: 350px; width: 350px; border: 70px solid #E5E4F0; border-radius: 50%; margin-top: -100px; margin-left: -100px;position: relative;">
  </div>
  <div class="slider">
    <div class="slide active" style="background-image: url('img/home.jpg')">
      <div class="containers">
        <div class="caption">
          <h1>"Title One"</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="slide" style="background-image: url('img/home1.jpg')">
      <div class="containers">
        <div class="caption">
          <h1>"Title Two"</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="slide" style="background-image: url('img/home2.jpg')">
      <div class="containers">
        <div class="caption">
          <h1>"Title Three"</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- controls  -->
  <div class="controls">
    <div class="prev">
      <</div>
        <div class="next">></div>
    </div>

    <!-- indicators -->
    <div class="indicator">
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: This is too much for the code,Just post the appropriate section of the code and your description is not catchy,who will read that?

Comment: sorry that description was not intentional.

Comment: `<div class="circle" style="height: 350px; width: 350px; border: 70px solid #E5E4F0; border-radius: 50%; margin-top: -100px; margin-left: -100px;position: relative;">` seems to be your circle...  position:absolute is maybe what you need ?

Comment: What is actually you want ? please describe more.

Comment: https://imgur.com/Im0K4YK  ---------------- Can you please see the image, Do you want to like this?

Comment: I mean you have `slider` with **background-image** then not showing the circle on top of the slider? isn't it?. Then try to add **z-index** for the solution.

Comment: can you please add expected output image?

Comment: Hi @AlArefin Was the below answer helpful to you? If so, please select a "correct" answer *(by clicking the checkmark beside an answer)* to close the question, or provide an answer yourself and choose that as the correct answer. Otherwise, please add comments below the answer or edit your original question to add more detail so that additional assistance can be provided. That will help us out. *(Also remember that upvoting is encouraged in order to reward answers that were particularly informative - and it is possible to also upvote the answer that you checkmark.)* Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The main reason this isn't working is because of `z-index` - your slides have a `z-index` of 1 so your circle needs to have a higher z-index to appear above the slide.

Also, as you want the circle to appear in a specific location at all times, you could consider using `position:absolute` - it gets a bad rap sometimes but that's just because it is often used inappropriately :) It is ideal for positioning an element precisely inside a parent container - that's what it was designed for!

These are the changes:

```
.circle {
    height: 350px;
    width: 350px;
    border: 70px solid #E5E4F0;
    border-radius: 50%;

    /* make sure the z-index value is higher than 
       all other elements you want this element to appear over */
    z-index:10; 

    /* set the position exactly where you want: */
    position: absolute;
    top: -100px;   /* these can be % values if you want it more responsive */
    left: -100px;
}
```

**Working example:** (FYI This shows the circle in the same place as in your example - if this is a responsive design I assume you have other code to adjust the circle position)

```css
.circle {
  height: 350px;
  width: 350px;
  border: 70px solid #E5E4F0;
  border-radius: 50%;

  /* make sure the z-index value is higher than 
     all other elements you want this element to appear over */
  z-index:10; 

  /* set the position exactly where you want: */
  position: absolute;
  top: -100px;
  left: -100px;
}

.home {
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.home .slide {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  z-index: 1;
  display: none;
  padding: 0 15px;
  animation: slide 2s ease;
}

.home .slide.active {
  display: flex;
}

@keyframes slide {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1);
    /*1.1*/
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}

.containers {
  max-width: 1170px;
  margin: auto;
}

.home .containers {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.home .caption {
  width: 50%;
}

.home .caption h1 {
  font-size: 42px;
  color: #000000;
  margin: 0;
}

.home .slide.active .caption h1 {
  opacity: 0;
  animation: captionText .5s ease forwards;
  animation-delay: 1s;
}

.home .caption p {
  font-size: 18px;
  margin: 15px 0 30px;
  color: #222222;
}

.home .slide.active .caption p {
  opacity: 0;
  animation: captionText .5s ease forwards;
  animation-delay: 1.2s;
}

.home .caption a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 30px;
  background-color: #000000;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.home .slide.active .caption a {
  opacity: 0;
  animation: captionText .5s ease forwards;
  animation-delay: 1.4s;
}

@keyframes captionText {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateX(-100px);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateX(0px);
  }
}

.home .controls .prev,
.home .controls .next {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  top: 50%;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  margin-top: -20px;
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #FF5722;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 40px;
  font-size: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all .5s ease;
}

.home .controls .prev:hover,
.home .controls .next:hover {
  background-color: #000000;
}

.home .controls .prev {
  left: 0;
}

.home .controls .next {
  right: 0;
}

.home .indicator {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: 30px;
  z-index: 2;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.home .indicator div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #FF5722;
  border-radius: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 25px;
  margin: 0 3px;
}

.home .indicator div.active {
  background-color: #000;
}
```

```html
<section class="home">
  <div class="circle">
  </div>
  <div class="slider">
    <div class="slide active" style="background-image: url('http://lorempixel.com/1000/350/animals/4')">
      <div class="containers">
        <div class="caption">
          <h1>"Title One"</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="slide" style="background-image: url('http://lorempixel.com/1000/350/animals/3')">
      <div class="containers">
        <div class="caption">
          <h1>"Title Two"</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="slide" style="background-image: url('http://lorempixel.com/1000/350/animals/2')">
      <div class="containers">
        <div class="caption">
          <h1>"Title Three"</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- controls  -->
  <div class="controls">
    <div class="prev">
      <</div>
        <div class="next">></div>
    </div>

    <!-- indicators -->
    <div class="indicator">
    </div>
</section>
```